# pass variables from template to views in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

On clicking on each location I have to fetch a text file from there. I need to pass these locations to the views.py to render the files.

template:

```
<script>
if(data.columns[j] == "outputFilePath"){
    var op = JSON.stringify(data.tableData[i][j]);
    op = op.substring(1, op.length-1)
    row.append("<td><a href='/dhl/outputDir'>" + op + "</a></td>")
}
</script>
```

views. py:

```
def outputDir(request,location):
    text_data = open("location/stdout", "rb").read()
    return HttpResponse(text_data, content_type="text/plain")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^dhl/outputDir',views.outputDir),
```

Comment: Are you sure that's from your template file? Because that looks more like a mix of php and python, and not proper jinja2-syntax

Comment: yes that is from a html file, code snippet here is the javascript part of the html

Comment: I see, I took the liberty to update the template code so it's a bit more obvious what happens :) However, can you emphasize what you need help with in your question? Currently your question states what you want to achieve, but it's not clear what you need help with. Take a minute to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need help for how to formulate your question and code.

Comment: How do I pass the variable 'op' to outputDir(views.py) so that I can fetch a file from the location---> text_data=open("op/stdout","rb").read() is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic template tags and default view functionality by passing parameters.

However, what you're trying to achieve, will make the view wide open for anyone to access folders in your application by entering any folder they want. You could add a list of allowed locations, which I have done in my solution below.

**Template**

```
if(data.columns[j] == "outputFilePath"){
    var op = JSON.stringify(data.tableData[i][j]);
    op = op.substring(1, op.length-1)
    row.append("<td><a href='/dhl/outputDir/" + op + "'>" + op + "</a></td>")
}
```

**views.py**

```
def outputDir(request, location):
    # Make sure to check if the location is in the list of allowed locations
    if location in allowed_locations:
        text_data = open(location + "/stdout", "rb").read()
        return HttpResponse(text_data, content_type="text/plain")
    else:
        return PermissionDenied
```

You also need to add a parameter to the url:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^dhl/outputDir/(?P<location>\w+)', views.outputDir),
```

Comment: @ShilpaNarayanan No problem! If you feel it was an adequate answer that helped you, consider marking it as an accepted solution. Or if you want to be open for more possible answers you can just leave it as it is :)